# iOS touch events on UIControl during UITableView scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

So I have a custom component that I made, which is an infinite scrolling UITableView with letters in it, so you can choose your initials for a game that I'm making.

I have three of them on the screen, with two buttons at the bottom, which are a "back" and "next" button. These buttons are 3D and are actually extended "UIControl" elements with some manual touch listeners to perform down and up Quartz 2D animations.

When I toss the UITableView and let them scroll, I am not able to get any touch events on the "back" and "next" buttons until they settle.

Anyone have any insight on why this would be? It seems odd because I can toss all three UITableViews at any point, but I can't touch either of my two custom UIControl buttons while they are scrolling.

This is how I'm listening for touch events on the UIControl. I'm new to iOS dev, so maybe there is a different/better way to listen?

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(onTouchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: After doing a little poking around... could the problem actually be that Quartz 2D drawing doesn't work during a UIScrollView/UITableView scrolling?

Comment: I've isolated the problem down to the animations I'm doing on the buttons. It is actually the NSTimer that I'm using to tween the values used for drawing. NSTimer doesn't run while a UIScrollView is in motion. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer. In my tweens for the 3D button, I am using:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kPRTweenFramerate target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I needed to change that to:

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:kPRTweenFramerate target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[timer fire];
```

This fixes the issue.

Although performance still seems fine during my basic use case, I am curious about the performance implications of using this method on a larger scale?